# Passing form data of Python CGI script to mySQL query

Tags: python, mysql, forms, cgi

I have been at this for about an hour and a half now, and I have not been able to devise a solution. I have been working with the following code:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
usrName = form.getvalue('uname')
usrPW = form.getvalue('psw')

while(usrPW == None):
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    usrName = form.getvalue('uname')
    usrPW = form.getvalue('psw')
    #usrName = str(usrName)
   # usrPW = str(usrPW)

connection = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost', user='golden', password='password', db='db', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        #create a new record in the database
        sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, (usrName, usrPW))
        # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save
        # your changes.
    connection.commit()
```

This is my attempt to pass data from my form, named `uname` and `psw`, respectively. This code worked when I had hard coded the values for `uname` and `psw` in the cursor.execute() call, however, when I try to send the form data to the query I get one of two results:

1. 404 with unable to find file
2. If I remove the `while(usrPW == None):` at the top (and the commands within the while loop), it executes immediately after the page is loaded- before I can type anything in and passes in nothing to both parameters, causing an error.

Any thoughts on how to fix this??

How do I properly pass data from a python CGI form to a mySQL database?

EDIT: Traceback update.

Provided I comment out the while loop and hardcode usrName and usrPW, I get the following:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2017 08:09:34] "GET /cgi-bin/login.py HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2017 08:09:39] code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2017 08:09:39] "GET /action_page.php?uname=a&psw=b HTTP/1.1" 404
```

However, the values get entered into the database, interestingly enough.

In the case that I leave the while loop running, it just loads indefinitely.

Comment: Complete traceback of your script failing would be nice.

Comment: @BoboDarph How do I do this? (I will gladly make this easier to diagnose however I can).

Comment: Hardcode the values you need to something inside the script and run it like your server would.

Comment: @BoboDarph Done.

Comment: I was thinking more along the line of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956696/debugging-cgi-python. But if your hardcoded data gets pushed to the DB, the problem lies somewhere outside your script most likely.

Comment: @BoboDarph You were right, upon closer inspection, all parts of script are running properly. It seems to be 404'ing when I submit the form. I'll look into this further. Thanks!

Comment: Lucky intuition I guess. IMO, always test individual scripts with mock data before integrating.